# I can't access all the elements in an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of objects `resultArray`:

```
resultArray= Array[object,object,....]
```

My object looks like

```
color:"value" ,diams:Array[n]
```

where `n` is number of elements inside the diams array.

Assuming

```
resultArray.diams = "0","3","5"
```

`"0","3","5"` should be index to access the global array diams
it looks like

```
var diams = [60,65,68,69,70,75,76,80,81,82,85,90];
```

I am trying to display all the selected information by user from this object. This is my code:

```
$.each(resultArray,function(key,value){
$("#renderedOBJ").append("<p id='p"+key+"'> color: "
+resultArray[key].color+"; Diameter :<span id='s"+key+"'>"
+resultArray[key].diams+"</span> </P>");
```

I got this:

```
color: purple; Diameter :0,2,3
```

but I wanted:

```
color: purple; Diameter :60,68,69
```

Thats why I tried to access the global array diams like this:

```
$.each(resultArray,function(key,value){
$("#renderedOBJ").append("<p id='p"+key+"'> Color: "+resultArray[key].color+
"; Diameter: <span id='s"+key+"'>"
+diams[resultArray[key].diams[key]]+"</span> </P>");
  })
```

But I got only the first value:

```
Color: pink; Diameter :60
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Almost none of this is valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var diams = [60,65,68,69,70,75,76,80,81,82,85,90];
resultArray= [{color:"purple",diams:["0","2","3"]},
{color:"yellow",diams:["0","3","5"]}
];
$.each(resultArray,function(key,value){
 $("#renderedOBJ").append("<p id='p"+key+"'> Color: "+resultArray[key].color+
"; Diameter: <span id='s"+key+"'>"
+resultArray[key].diams.map(function(a) {return diams[parseInt(a)]}).join(', ')+"</span> </P>");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="renderedOBJ"></div>
```

Comment: actually I tried map but I didn't knew that I have to parse the index. thanks a lot. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` for that:

```
resultArray[key].diams.map(i => diams[i])
```

Or, if you want to stick to jQuery and avoid ES5/6:

```
$.map(resultArray[key].diams, function(i) {
    return diams[i];
})
```